# WHERE do you set up the applicationIconBadgeNumber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo

Does anyone know WHERE do you set up the applicationIconBadgeNumber for React Native / Expo application for iOS & Android?

Im using React Native, Visual Studio Code and Expo.

Like, on WHICH Page / File, etc ?

I cannot seem to find: [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber

If you can please list the Steps to get this working, and any installs (if needed).

I already have Push Notifications working on my App, but Im trying to set this up now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know WHERE do you set up the applicationIconBadgeNumber for React Native / Expo application for iOS & Android?

Expo API is pretty clear about this, I googled your question and it linked me to it:
[`Expo.Notifications.setBadgeNumberAsync(number)`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications.html#app-icon-badge-number-ios)

> Like, on WHICH Page / File, etc ?

This is a pretty open ended question. You could link `setBadgeNumberAsync` to your redux in an action.

Or just put it anywhere I guess ‍♀️ it's a static method that excepts a number, I would use the redux approach though!